# AEM6: Whats the simplest way to to add a long field label without splitting to next line

Tags: extjs, content-management-system, adobe, aem

I have a widget checkbox with a long field label, I just want the field label remain in the same line without spilling over to next line.

Whats the simplest way to to add a long field label without splitting to next line.

Comment: Here long means lengthy, and not a data type.

Comment: You can use custom css to give additional width on checkbox label.

Answer (score 0):

Since CQ / AEM 5.6 use ExtJS3 I guess you can use [labelStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Checkbox-cfg-labelStyle) property and define your radio like

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    fieldLabel: 'Checkbox looooooooooong title',
    labelStyle: 'width: 250px;'
}
```